# NVD3 / D3 deriving variables

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently I'm using NVD3 library of D3.
How can I derive variables from other variables? 
Like if I have

```
var a1 = [{x:1, y: 10}, {x:2, y:3}, {x:3, y:5}],
```

so how should I get `b1`, that is lets say  squared values of `y` of `a1`, with the same `x` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a pure javascript question.  The following will work:

```
var b1 = a1.map(function(elm) { return {x: elm.x, y: elm.y*elm.y}; });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Great! 
Also how should I derive a new variable c1 using both, a1 and b1. For example their product, or sum, or whatever.

Comment: Since b1 was derived from a1, you only need a1 to derive c1 as well, so you can use the exact same method.  If you had unrelated a1 and b1, the simplest thing would probably be to use an oridnary `for (var i=0; i<a1.length; i++)` loop, and use the index `i` to get the current elm from both a1 and b1, make your calculation on them, and then add them to a result array.